# Why i get $ undefined error while using a jQuery plugin in ASP.Net Mvc application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

May be this question is too simple but for me as newbie to the programming took me 2 days to find a solution and no luck yet.
I am using ezPlus jQuery plugin in asp.net mvc application but when i run the application and put a break point in a function using Firebug i get the $ undefined error. Worth to mention that i placed jquery and ezPlus references at the top of my view in head section but still getting error. I added the references to the bundle config too but no luck either.
Here is what i tried.
View :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Zom";
    //Layout = "~/Views/shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Zom</h2>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>jQuery elevateZoom Demo</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ez-plus.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Gallery & Lightbox</h1>


    <img id="zoom_03" src="~/images/small/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="~/images/large/image1.jpg" />

    <div id="gallery_01">
        <a href="#" data-image="~/images/small/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="~/images/large/image1.jpg">
            <img id="img_01" src="~/images/thumb/image1.jpg" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-image="~/images/small/image2.jpg" data-zoom-image="~/images/large/image2.jpg">
            <img id="img_01" src="~/images/thumb/image2.jpg" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-image="~/images/small/image3.jpg" data-zoom-image="~/images/large/image3.jpg">
            <img id="img_01" src="~/images/thumb/image3.jpg" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-image="~/images/small/image4.jpg" data-zoom-image="~/images/large/image4.jpg">
            <img id="img_01" src="~/images/thumb/image4.jpg" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-image="~/images/small/image5.jpg" data-zoom-image="~/images/large/image5.jpg">
            <img id="img_01" src="~/images/thumb/image5.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#zoom_03").ezPlus({
            gallery: 'gallery_01',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            galleryActiveClass: "active",
            imageCrossfade: true,
            loadingIcon: "images/spinner.gif"
        });

        $("#zoom_03").bind("click", function (e) {
            var ez = $('#zoom_03').data('ezPlus');
            ez.closeAll(); //NEW: This function force hides the lens, tint and window
            $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
            return false;
        });

    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Bundle config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.ez-plus.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"));
```

And finally i rendered the bundles in my `_Layout` :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Firebug:
[image: Fire Bug Error]

Comment: If you have included `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`, then you should not be including `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` and `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ez-plus.js"></script>` (you just loading them twice. And according to [this](https://www.versioneye.com/javascript/igorlino:ez-plus/1.1.8), you need `jquery-1.11.2` or higher.

Comment: check if both the library are loaded by clicking the network

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well if i add the references to my view then i don't use layout is that make any difference?

Comment: The main issue is that your include `jquery-1.10.2.js` but the plugin required minimum version `1.11.2` or higher

Comment: @StephenMuecke where can i get that jquery version?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i added the version jquery-1.12.0 but no luck :(

Comment: Make sure you have referenced the jquery file only once (check both your applayout, views) Also if you have included in the head section then no need of the bundles.

Comment: @Reddy i did and there is no conflict. The code above works in simple html but don't work with my view. :(

Comment: And why is there a head and body section again in your view?

Comment: @Reddy no that's all what i pasted above in my view. nothing more.

Comment: Remove the head section, And remove the body tags, just keep the body elemets content in your view. You already have a head and body in your Layout page

Comment: @Reddy but i don't render the layout from my view. i mean i don't have Layout for my view?

Comment: Which line of code is the error actually occurring? (and note it should be `$("#zoom_03").click(function (e) { ... ` (not `.bind()`)

Comment: It will use the _Layout by default. So just make sure the jquery is referenced in the _layout page only once, If you carefully see the layout page body tag you can find a line with ` @RenderBody()` , This is a place holder for your view. When you return View from controller the part of view is inserted at this  @RenderBody() line. So you will have layout and your view together in the browser. Hope I didnt confuse you

Comment: @StephenMuecke here is the line i get the error $(document).ready(function () {, stephen it is not like when i run the application and i get an error this is when i put a break point via firebug then it shows me the error

Comment: @Reddy now i get this error doing what you said. typeof JSON!="undefined"&&(window._vwdJSON=JSON),typeof define!="undefined"&&(window._vwdDefine=define,define=null)
;

Comment: I see you have commented the layout line in your view But it will still use the default Layout (unless you have chosen a partial view option in visual studio while adding the view file). Try setting the Layout = null; instead of commenting it

Comment: Is it a return View() or return PartialView() from your controller?

Comment: @Reddy you mean i have to add references back to the view and then set layout to null?

Comment: @Reddy return view("Zom");

Comment: If you dont want to use the LayoutPage then set Layout = null, But yes you must have all the head tag body tag and references in your view

Comment: @Reddy did it not working either....

Comment: hmmm not sure what else might be causing the issue.